# Running SWI Prolog via Terminal Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to run prolog from terminal. I have installed version 7.2.2 and added it to my environment path using the command:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Then to get started I typed

```
swipl
```

but this error gets returned instead:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I am new to this, kindly help me out. I know I can run the application by double clicking on it but I'm more comfortable working from the terminal..

My Mac version is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I removed the GUI version in my applications folder. Don't need it to run SWI-Prolog from command line. Simply go to terminal window and type in:

```
brew tap homebrew/x11
```

after the above command executes, enter:

```
brew install swi-prolog --HEAD
```

and now `swipl` should work:

```
Maryams-MacBook-Pro:~ maryam$ swipl
```

returns

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.3)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).
```

Yay! ready to go. Let's test this:

```
?- ['/Users/maryam/Downloads/familyTree.pl'].

true.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install Swi-prolog as follows:

```
sudo port -d selfupdate

sudo port install swi-prolog
```

After this, you can check the installed Swi-prolog (swipl) at

```
/opt/local/bin/
```

And now it should work

```
swipl




Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.2.2)
 Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
 SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
 and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
 Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

 For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

 ?-
```